# What do the colors mean in java language specification - diffs version?

Tags: java

I downloaded the jsl [PDF with diffs from Java SE 5.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7-diffs.pdf) for java 7 - and planning to read it
err in my summer holiday. Some paragraphs are red, some blue and some green. I guess those are the differences. What do they mean ?

Comment: You should be asking Oracle for this, not SO.

Comment: @pradeep:In a way that goes for many questions asked here see related on the left.

Comment: 1. open the JLS version 5 - 2. Open the JLS version 7 - 3. open the diff file - 4. You should easily understand what the colors mean.

Comment: @assylias:Usually this info is on a legend somewhere - that's not an answer!

Comment: I feel the treatment of my question is unjust - search SO for "Java Language Specification" and check questions that are much more unrelated to the FAQ and still upvoted/open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors mean the following:

- Black - Not changed
- Green - Added text
- Red   - Removed text
- Blue  - Text format change.

Comment: Thanks :) - if you could please add your sources (I suspected it but could not find anything, that's why I asked) I will accept your answer

Comment: I ask this question to myself while a go. Black, red and green are obvious. The blue after checking was also obvious.